# Animation on Toggle Change with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I am building a simple settings screen.

When then first setting is activated, the Speed Control appears. When it's turned off, the Speed Control disappears.

Based on what I know about SwiftUI, this should automatically animate based on the code below, but instead it just appears and disappears.

How can I make this animation nicer with SwiftUI, so it slides down from the cell above it, like in [this presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/) at 53:00?

[image: GIF of setting animation]

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {

    @ObjectBinding var settingsStore: SettingsStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsStore.settingActivated.animation(.basic(duration: 3, curve: .easeInOut))) {
                    Text("Setting Activated")
                }
                if settingsStore.settingActivated {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Speed Control")
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "tortoise")
                            Slider(value: .constant(10), from: 0, through: 50, by: 1)
                            Image(systemName: "hare")
                        }
                    }.transition(.opacity)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
        }
    }
}

class SettingsStore: BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var settingActivated: Bool = UserDefaults.settingActivated {
        didSet {

            UserDefaults.settingActivated = settingActivated

            didChange.send()
        }
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {

    private struct Keys {
        static let settingActivated = "SettingActivated"
    }

    static var settingActivated: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Keys.settingActivated)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.settingActivated)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It must be a bug. If you remove the embedding NavigationView and replace `Form` with `Stack`, you will see that animations start to work. The only reason I can think for that behavior, is a bug. You should file one with Apple.

Comment: It is a bug - a known issue (although I don't have a reference for it) that when NavigationView is enabled within the view, the animation doesn't work as you'd expect.

Comment: The issue still persists on Xcode 14.1 using NavigationStack

Answer (score 2):

The same bug is still present in iOS 15 and iOS 16.
You now can use the property @AppStorage which takes care of reading and writing the value in the default store, but animations still don't work with that.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage("SettingActivated") var settingActivated: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: $settingActivated.animation(.basic(duration: 3, curve: .easeInOut))) {
                Text("Activate Setting")
            }
            if settingActivated {
                Text("Setting Activated")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found a workaround which requires little extra code and then works fine.
You need the usual @State property for SwiftUI to run animations, and you can just set this whenever the @AppStorage property changes (1):

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage("SettingActivated") var settingActivated: Bool = false
    @State private var settingShown: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Activate Setting", isOn: $settingActivated.animation())
                .onChange(of: value) { value in
                    withAnimation {settingShown = value}  // 1)
                }
            if settingShown {
                Text("Setting Activated")
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            settingShown = settingActivated  // 2)
        }
    }
}
```

However, since you cannot initialize the @State from the @AppStorage, you need to do this in .onAppear. (2)

And that's it. Animations in Forms and Lists, triggered by @AppStorage toggle.